# looping over array with thead and tbody tags in react

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, meteor

I am trying to add thead and tbody tags to my table in react. The source data is one array where the first index contains the header and the rest is the table body.

```
    return (
      <div>
        {index == 1 && <tbody>}
      <tr key={index}>
        {tableData(false, row.value)}
      </tr>
        {index == pivot.data.table.length && </tbody>}
      </div>
    );
```

Within the loop above I get unexpected token at `{index == pivot.data.table.length && </tbody>}`

Full code and sandbox are below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Pivot from "quick-pivot";
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';

class PivotTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  createTable() {
    const dataArray = [
      ["name", "gender", "house", "age"],
      ["Jon", "m", "Stark", 14],
      ["Arya", "f", "Stark", 10],
      ["Cersei", "f", "Baratheon", 38],
      ["Tywin", "m", "Lannister", 67],
      ["Tyrion", "m", "Lannister", 34],
      ["Joffrey", "m", "Baratheon", 18],
      ["Bran", "m", "Stark", 8],
      ["Jaime", "m", "Lannister", 32],
      ["Sansa", "f", "Stark", 12]
    ];

    const rowsToPivot = ["name"];
    const colsToPivot = ["house", "gender"];
    const aggregationDimension = "age";
    const aggregator = "sum";

    const pivot = new Pivot(
      dataArray,
      rowsToPivot,
      colsToPivot,
      aggregationDimension,
      aggregator
    );

    console.log("pivot.data", pivot.data, "pivot.data.table", pivot.data.table);
    const tableData = (heading, row) => {
      return row.map(cell => {
        if (heading) {
          return (
            <th>
              {cell}
            </th>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <td>
              {cell}
            </td>
          );
        }
      });
    };

    return pivot.data.table.map((row, index) => {
      if (index == 0) {
        return (
          <thead>
            <tr key={index}>
              {tableData(true, row.value)}
            </tr>
          </thead>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <div>
            {index == 1 && <tbody>}
          <tr key={index}>
            {tableData(false, row.value)}
          </tr>
            {index == pivot.data.table.length && </tbody>}
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        {this.createTable()}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

render(<PivotTable />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vgDE6rOEM

How can I fix this?

The easiest way to do this I would assume is to create a seperate function that calls the data again, creates a new array and only creates the heading. The problem when I do that is that it will probably decrease performance a lot.

Can I have this all in one call or what is the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: The unexpected token is probably `<` - you can't output HTML elements like you did within a JavaScript expression in React `{...}`

Comment: @chazsolo I find this very strange since the official docs mention you can do it this way: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator do you have any idea why this does not work?

Comment: You're right... I'm not sure what I was reading. Ignore that :)

Comment: Sorry I need to ask... why is there a `<div>` inside a table?

Comment: @lumio I added it because else I get an error from react that if I want to render multiple components that they should always be enclosed by tags. I would rather like to exclude them but I don't see how.

Comment: I usually use `<tbody>` and `<thead>` for that

Comment: @lumio the problem here is that I don't want each tbody row to have tbody as enclosing tag. (see the map function). But I want to surround ALL  table  body rows at once with the tbody tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Pivot from 'quick-pivot';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class PivotTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
```

getGapData get's the data when it is ready. If not it will return the string 'loading'.

```
  getGapData() {
    //const dataArray = [
    //['name', 'gender', 'house', 'age'],
    //['Jon', 'm', 'Stark', 14],
    //['Arya', 'f', 'Stark', 10],
    //['Cersei', 'f', 'Baratheon', 38],
    //['Tywin', 'm', 'Lannister', 67],
    //['Tyrion', 'm', 'Lannister', 34],
    //['Joffrey', 'm', 'Baratheon', 18],
    //['Bran', 'm', 'Stark', 8],
    //['Jaime', 'm', 'Lannister', 32],
    //['Sansa', 'f', 'Stark', 12],
    //];
    if (this.props.ready) {
      const dataArray = this.props.data;

      const rowsToPivot = ['index'];
      const colsToPivot = ['period'];
      const aggregationDimension = 'visits';
      const aggregator = 'sum';

      const pivot = new Pivot(
        dataArray,
        rowsToPivot,
        colsToPivot,
        aggregationDimension,
        aggregator
      );

      //this.setState({ headerData: pivot.data.table[0] });
      //this.setState({bodyData: pivot.data.table.slice(1) });
      return pivot.data.table;
    } else {
      return 'loading';
    }
  }
```

Before the render() return we execute the getGapData function. Only having to execute it once.

I am working with slice and the first index of the array to display the head and body data. I can just wrap this code with the thead and tbody tags solving my problem.

```
  render() {
    console.log(this.getGapData());
    const gap = this.getGapData();
    return (
      <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {gap != 'loading' &&
              gap[0].value.map(data => {
                return (
                  <th>
                    {data}
                  </th>
                );
              })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {gap != 'loading' &&
            gap.slice(1).map(row => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  {row.value.map(data => {
                    return (
                      <td>
                        {data}
                      </td>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally use ternary operators for such patterns, try:

```
return (
      <div>
        {index == 1 ? <tbody> : <div />}
      <tr key={index}>
        {tableData(false, row.value)}
      </tr>
        {index == pivot.data.table.length ? </tbody> : <div />}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Might be an error further up in the file... does your linter report anything or do you only see this when the project builds?

Comment: I tried with your ternary operators ( or my solution ) and when I remove them the code works but does not include any tbody tags.

Comment: Oh wait I think I know why - these statements have to embed both the opening and closing tag, you can't in one block create the opening tag and in another block create the closing.

Comment: I think you might be right. I got it working.will post the answer when possible.